# How do you hot link an external image from a Media Wiki site?

Tags: images, mediawiki, hotlinking

What is the syntax for showing an externally hosted image in a media wiki page?  [The media wiki help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Syntax) doesn't seem to cover that scenario.

I've tried several things that don't work:

```
[http://example.com/image.jpg]
[[File:http://example.com/image.jpg]]
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
```

Comment: In more recent versions there is also: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowImageTag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example `[http://example.com/image.jpg]` is correct.

You will need to enable this by setting `$wgAllowExternalImages` to true in your configuration file. The default is false. Optionally, you can set `$wgAllowExternalImagesFrom` to allow exceptions while `$wgAllowExternalImages` remains set to false. You can also use `$wgEnableImageWhitelist` to allow exceptions based upon regular expressions.

You will likely need to copy the appropriate line from DefaultSettings.php to LocalSettings.php.

Here are some links (in order):

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImagesFrom
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableImageWhitelist

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `[http://example.com/image.jpg]` is ***not*** correct.

The correct way to insert an external image into a wikimedia page is
`http://example.com/image.jpg` eg. no square brackets.

Of course, make sure that you have added `$wgAllowExternalImages = true` to your configuration file  to enable display of the image, as wikimedia defaults to not allowing externally hosted images.