# mediawiki - make thumbnails of external images

Tags: images, mediawiki, wiki

So I have the code `[[File:example.jpg|thumb|caption]]`. This works fine for local images and files, but I want to host some images externally. I can't just replace example.jpg with a link though, because it still thinks it's a local file.

Comment: Related: [How do you hot link an external image from a Media Wiki site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74564/how-do-you-hot-link-an-external-image-from-a-media-wiki-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417275/2234742), resizing external images using features such as `thumb` cannot be done.

> From [the MediaWiki manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgAllowExternalImages#Thumbnails_of_external_images):
>
> For resizing images in mediawiki they need to have a row in image table of database containing dimensions and other information of image so you can't resize external images.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505295/2234742) suggests resizing your image in CSS, as a workaround:

> If client-side resizing is sufficient, you could probably whip something up with CSS...
>
> Wrap the image you want to resize in a div or span and give it a
> particular class like:
>
> ```
> <div class="image100px">http://example.com/path/to/image.jpeg</div>
> ```
>
> And in the [[MediaWiki:Common.css]] page on the wiki add an entry like
> this:
>
> ```
> .image100px img { width: 100px; }
> ```
>
> (Note that due to caching of the CSS you might have to force a reload
> to see the update.)

However, that won't get you the nice caption box.